# Extract value string from URL

Tags: url, go

I want to retrieve a value from a URL. Provided I have a URL such as `http://myurl.com/theValue1/iWantToRetrieveThis`, I want to split this value and want to retrieve `theValue1` and `iWantToRetrieveThis`. How can I do this?

I tried the code below but it seems that it's only retrieving the query string:

```
func decodeGetTokenRequest(_ context.Context, r *http.Request) (request interface{}, err error) {
    fmt.Println("decoding here", path.Base(r.URL))
    return getTokenRequest{
        SellerID: r.URL.Query().Get("sellerid"), <<--- THis is empty
        Scope:    r.URL.Query().Get("scope"), <<-- This is also empty
        Authorization: Validation{
            credential: r.Header.Get("ETM-API-AUTH-KEY"),
        },
    }, nil
}
```

Comment: Try this: `strings.Split(r.URL.Path, "/")[1]`

Comment: If you tried that code you should have noticed that it doesn't compile. r.URL is of type *url.URL and `path.Base(r.URL.Path)` works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just had to go with @Rafal answer since what I'm trying to retrieve is not a query parameter but part of the url.